# Поиск и замена фрагмента текста в файле

Tags: java

Нужен код на Java, который откроет файл, будет искать в нём вхождения определённого фрагмента текста, после чего заменит их все на другой фрагмент текста и сохранит полученный результат обратно в исходный файл.

Например, программа должна открыть файл file.txt, найти в нём все вхождения `31415` и заменить их на текст `число ПИ`.

Answer (score 8):

Пишу ответ, чтобы люди, которые изучали Java в прошлом веке, знали: в наши дни (Java 7 и новее) задача решается по факту в одну строчку.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.*;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class ReplaceInFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String fileName = "file.txt";
        String search = "31415";
        String replace = "число ПИ";
        Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
        Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
        Files.write(path,
            new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset).replace(search, replace)
                .getBytes(charset));
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, что для вашей задачи надо знать также кодировку файла. Я указал UTF_8. У вас может быть другая (например, `Charset.forName("cp1251")` — русская Windows-кодировка). Приведённое решение самое простое, но оно читает весь файл в память. Если файл в память не влазит, оно не подойдёт.

Comment: спс но Эклипс видает ошибку в консоли: Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: test.txt
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
 at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
 at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
 at java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Unknown Source)
 at ReplaceInFile.main(ReplaceInFile.java:13)

Comment: @TСPakko, ну нету файла test.txt, он об этом пишет. Чего непонятного? Обычно эклипс запускает приложения, устанавливая текущую директорию в корень проекта (ту же папку, где лежит файл .project). Убедитесь, что ваш test.txt там же лежит. Или настройте Run configuration, чтобы рабочая директория при запуске была какая вам надо.

Comment: да-да уже сам понял)) я просто прописал вместе с названием и путь к файлу все заработало. спасибо большое. знаю многого хочу, но можно чтобы код сам определял какая кодировка текста в файле?)

Comment: @TСPakko, задайте отдельный вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Взяв за основу данные примеры, вы без труда составите нужную вам программу.Удачи!

Открыть файл

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadFileExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("C:/robots.txt");

        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {

            System.out.println("Total file size to read (in bytes) : "+ fis.available());

            int content;
            while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
                // convert to char and display it
                System.out.print((char) content);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Замена текста

```
String myFile;
myFile.replaceAll("12345","замена");//Заменит все вхождения 12345 на "замена"
```

Запись в файл

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WriteToFileExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String content = "This is the content to write into file";

            File file = new File("/users/mkyong/filename.txt");

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content);
            bw.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```